# Flutter : How to call variables in stateful widget outside of class?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i try to call variable file? and string of image from here :

```
class Phototake extends StatefulWidget {
  static final theKey = GlobalKey<_PhototakeState>();
  Phototake({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Phototake> createState() => _PhototakeState();
}

class _PhototakeState extends State<Phototake> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  // This is the file that will be used to store the image

  File? _image;
  String? image;
  String imagename = "Outlet Picture 1";
}
```

to diffrent class here

```
class _CheckoutPageState extends State<CheckoutPage> {
  late final Phototake phototake = Phototake();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
```

i cannot call the variable inside phototake and i can't initialize _PhototakeState, how do i call variable in _PhototakeState to _CheckoutPageState. i call phototake in stepper like this :

```
Step(
          title: const Text('Taking Inspection Photo'),
          content: phototake,
          state: _stepState(6),
          isActive: _currentStep == 6,
        ),
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you need to share state between widgets, you must use some form of state management.  Perhaps you skipped the codelabs in flutter.dev - I suggest you return to them.

Comment: You can pass data while navigating to or from a page to another. In this case I think file has to be passed from ```Phototake ``` to ```CheckoutPageState```. For that you can pass data via ```Navigator.pop(context, <file>)```

Answer (score 0):

use passing data via navigator like example :

```
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/checkout", arguments: {
                    "file": file,
                    "image": image
      });
```

you can receive passed data :

```
var args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments! as Map;
var file = args['file'];
var image = args['image'];
```

Comment: but i use stepper, not button, i have update my questions